# How can I get postgresql text searching to use search term order in rank

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

The following PostgreSQL text search

```
select 
    ID, DISPLAY_NAME, 
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', display_name), query) as RANK
from 
    my_table, 
    to_tsquery('english', 'John:*&Bernard:*') as query
where 
    to_tsvector('english', display_name) @@ query
    order by RANK DESC
```

produces

```
ID    DISPLAY_NAME         RANK   
=====================================
82683 "BERNARD JOHN SMBZh" 0.05
63815 "BERNARD JOHN []zkP" 0.05
68204 "BERNARD JOHN uPmYB" 0.05
29666 "John Bernard iECx"  0.05
44256 "John Bernard DpIff" 0.05
52601 "BERNARD JOHN ivRTX" 0.05
80250 "BERNARD JOHN b'nVp" 0.0430677
```

but what I really would like is for the "John Bernard*" records to have a higher rank because the terms in the "document" appear in the same order as the query. Is this possible?

e.g. A result like this:

```
ID    DISPLAY_NAME         RANK   
=====================================
29666 "John Bernard iECx"  0.10
44256 "John Bernard DpIff" 0.10
82683 "BERNARD JOHN SMBZh" 0.05
63815 "BERNARD JOHN []zkP" 0.05
68204 "BERNARD JOHN uPmYB" 0.05
52601 "BERNARD JOHN ivRTX" 0.05
80250 "BERNARD JOHN b'nVp" 0.0430677
```

Cheers
Craig

Comment: Add another ts_query without the wildcards. Then in the select, add another to_rank_cd on the new query. This will need to be left joined for the cases where the less selective query matches but not the more selective. Now, order it by major rank and minor rank.

Comment: What version of postgres are you using? `select  to_tsquery('english', 'John:*&Bernard:*');` gives a syntax error on 8.3

Comment: Ok, must be 8.4 or above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to consider a solution involving another ranking mechanism alongside tsearch as it [does not handle phrases](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/tsearch/tsearch-intro.html).

How about something like:

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, display_name text);
insert into my_table(display_name) values ('John Bernard iECx'), 
                                          ('John Bernard DpIff'), 
                                          ('BERNARD JOHN SMBZh'), 
                                          ('BERNARD JOHN b''nVp');
select
    ID, DISPLAY_NAME,
    ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english', display_name), query)
      *case when display_name~*'.*john bernard.*' then 2 else 1 end as RANK
from
    my_table,
    to_tsquery('english', 'John:*&Bernard:*') as query
where
    to_tsvector('english', display_name) @@ query
    order by RANK DESC;
```

producing:

```
 id |    display_name    |       rank
----+--------------------+-------------------
  1 | John Bernard iECx  | 0.200000002980232
  2 | John Bernard DpIff | 0.200000002980232
  3 | BERNARD JOHN SMBZh | 0.100000001490116
  4 | BERNARD JOHN b'nVp | 0.100000001490116
```